# Refresh Map/Activity After turn on GPS using prompt

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

Refresh Map/Activity After turn on GPS using prompt.
I have done this but it doesn't refresh the activity. 
Here is my code:

```
public void showSettingsAlert(){

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // Setting Icon to Dialog
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            HomeActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            loadData();
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

How do I refresh the activity?

checkGPS();

private void checkGPS() {
        if (!SmartLocation.with(this).location().state().locationServicesEnabled() || !SmartLocation.with(this).location().state().isAnyProviderAvailable())  {
            maketoast("Location Services are not enabled!!");
            showSettingsAlert();
        }
    }

Comment: Refresh the map in your activity's onResume method.

Comment: Add your map class code.!

Comment: It gets the Activity in infinite loop

Comment: post your code.

Comment: I have added code of checkGPS();

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if(GPS on){
         activity refresh..
    }else{
         showSettingsAlert();
    }
}
```

Comment: It gets the Activity in infinite loop